# Register controllers and services angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes, frameworks

I'm starting to configure my application with Angularjs, I am following a route guide but I can not make the project run

i dont know how to register my controllers and services for load 
dynamically when i change pages... :/  y created mi appConfig file for configure my routes.

My directory.

[image]

my app config:

```
angular.module('library.crud', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html'
          })
          .when('/book', {
              templateUrl: 'app/views/book.html',
              controller: 'bookController',
              controllerAs: 'vm'
          })
          .when('/books', {
              templateUrl: '../app/views/books.html',
              controller: 'booksController',
              controllerAs: 'vm'
          })
          .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
          });
});
```

example controller:

```
(function () {
  'use stritct';

  angular
  .module('library.crud')
  .controller('booksController', booksController);

  booksController.inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'bookService'];

  function booksController($rootScope, $scope, bookService) {
      var vm = this;
  }
})();
```

example service:

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

  angular
     .module('library.crud', [])
     .factory('bookService', bookService);

  bookService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

  function bookService($http, $q) {
      var service = {

      };
      return service;
  }
 })();
```

indexHTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--script imports, angular, jquery, bootstrap etc... -->
    <script src="app/appConfig.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="library.crud">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#!/home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#!/books">Books</a></li>

    <div class="container">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

at what time do my HTML pages know which controller to invoke and where is it located? how register my services ?

When i enter a books options from menu, the console show the next error:

> The controller with the name 'booksController' is not registered.

UPDATED INDEX.HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

   <link rel ="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   <script src="resources/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="resources/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="resources/angular/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

   <script src="app/appConfig.js"></script>
   <script src="app/services/book.service.js"></script>
   <script src="app/views/controllers/books.controller.js"></script>
   <script src="app/views/controllers/book.controller.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body ng-app="library.crud">

   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
       <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#!/home">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#!/books">Books</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </nav>

   <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your index.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two things in your code,

(i) You dont have to add dependencies in your code.

```
angular.module('library.crud').factory('bookService', bookService);
```

(ii) Add reference for your controller and service in your index.html.

```
 <script src="app/appConfig.js"></script>
 <script src="app/service.js"></script>
 <script src="app/controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias, corrija lo que propuso pero el error persiste: /

Comment: he controller with the name 'booksController' is not registered.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason this error occurs when everything else looks ok is because  you did not include your js files in your index.html. Based on your screenshot, it looks like you have your controllers and services in separate files. Make sure you put them after your appConfig.js file in index.html.

Another issue I see is in your service file.

```
angular
 .module('library.crud', [])
 .factory('bookService', bookService);
```

should be

```
angular
 .module('library.crud')
 .factory('bookService', bookService);
```

If you include square brackets as a second parameter in the .module line,  angular will think you are creating a new app instead of trying to register your service/controller to your existing app.

Also, it is highly recommend to use ui-router instead of NgRoute in any Angular1.x applications: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Hello, I already corrected my service and added the dependencies in my index.html but the error persisted: /
The controller with the name 'booksController' is not registered.

Comment: Cant really debug further without your codebase. I would just recommend to double check that you are correctly registering all services, controllers and factories (not passing in square brackets to angular.module('library.crud')). You can try to make a plunkr and post the link in your post.